# "Commence many frustrating/embarrassing mistakes." meaning in the below context

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does the writer mean by the sentence in bold? (He is a native Kiwi English speaker.)

> Hi everyone,
>   The door code is now 1111.
>   **Commence many frustrating/embarrassing mistakes.**
>   Regards,
>   David

Comment: My guess is that he is making a joke and wants to say that people will start to use the wrong old code and it will be embarrassing. Just needed yo make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is just a joke. Notice the use of "commence" — normally used only in formal contexts, in an informal setting. The grammar is very relaxed, in fact, it is arguably ungrammatical, as you can't "commence a mistake". But not a worry because it's just a joke.

Answer (score 1):

It's a slightly cheeky way to note that the change will probably result in many frustrating/embarrassing mistakes - jokingly phrased as if the writer himself officially "initiates" the mistakes.